# Выбор свободной ОС

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ос

По работе требуется выбрать какой-либо дистрибутив Linux OS, бесплатный для комерческого использования для запуска на виртуальной машине. Пока тестовый вариант работает на Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (также пробовал Ubuntu Server). Могу ли я использовать данные ОС свободно в коммерческих целях или какие ОС для этого лучше выбрать?

Comment: Ubuntu LTS вполне подходящий выбор для начала. Использование в коммерческих целях, не связанных с продажей самой Ubuntu полностью разрешено https://ubuntu.com/legal/intellectual-property-policy